# HTML password is not same length

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am doing this HTML page and don't know why this two password area isn't the same size. I have made a copy-paste from the first one so its 100% identical. 
I just started making myth first HTML page for a semester project and need help.

When I see how it looks it looks like this:

[image: HTML output]

```js
</script>  
<div show/hide password>
<script>
function pass(){
    var d=document.getElementById('s1');
    var e=document.getElementById('show_f').value;
    var f=document.getElementById('show_f').type; 

    if(d.value=="show"){
        var f= document.getElementById('show_f').type="text";
        var g=document.getElementById('show_f').value=e;
        d.value="Hide";

    } else{
        var f= document.getElementById('show_f').type="password";
        var g=document.getElementById('show_f').value=e;
        d.value="show";
     }     
  }   
  </script> 
  <script>
function pass2(){
    var d=document.getElementById('s2');
    var e=document.getElementById('show_g').value;
    var f=document.getElementById('show_g').type; 

    if(d.value=="show"){
        var f= document.getElementById('show_g').type="text";
        var g=document.getElementById('show_g').value=e;
        d.value="Hide";

    } else{
        var f= document.getElementById('show_g').type="password";
        var g=document.getElementById('show_g').value=e;
        d.value="show";
     }     
  }   
  </script> 
  </div>
```

```css
.password {
  margin-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
 <table>
    <tr>
<th>  <form action="/action_page.php" >
  <!-- password for Wi-Fi login -->
      <p class="text" class="arial"  style="font-size:20px;">Password: <input style="font-size:20px"  id="show_f" type="password" name="pass_f" maxlength='30'  size='15' class="password" >
  <input type="button" onclick="pass()" id="s1" value="show" style="height:25px; margin-left:5px;margin-top:3px;">
<input type="submit" value="connect" onclick="alert('Done!')" ></th>
<!-- password for sql login -->
  <th><p class="text" class="arial"  style="font-size:20px;">Password: <input style="font-size:20px" id="show_g"  type="password" name="pass_g" maxlength='30'  size='15' class="password" >
    <input type="button" onclick="pass2()" id="s2" value="show" style="height:25px; margin-left:5px;margin-top:3px;">
        <input type="submit" value="connect" onclick="alert('Done!')" ></th>

  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: remove `margin-left: 50px;` and set `body{margin:0}`

Comment: Don't help at all

Answer (score 0):

Please look carefully, both are same `width` and `height`, over. isn't it?

```js
function pass(){
    var d=document.getElementById('s1');
    var e=document.getElementById('show_f').value;
    var f=document.getElementById('show_f').type; 

    if(d.value=="show"){
        var f= document.getElementById('show_f').type="text";
        var g=document.getElementById('show_f').value=e;
        d.value="Hide";

    } else{
        var f= document.getElementById('show_f').type="password";
        var g=document.getElementById('show_f').value=e;
        d.value="show";
     }     
  }   
  </script> 
  <script>
function pass2(){
    var d=document.getElementById('s2');
    var e=document.getElementById('show_g').value;
    var f=document.getElementById('show_g').type; 

    if(d.value=="show"){
        var f= document.getElementById('show_g').type="text";
        var g=document.getElementById('show_g').value=e;
        d.value="Hide";

    } else{
        var f= document.getElementById('show_g').type="password";
        var g=document.getElementById('show_g').value=e;
        d.value="show";
     }     
  }
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
}

th {
    background: red;
}
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
<th>  <form action="/action_page.php" >
  <!-- password for Wi-Fi login -->
      <p class="text" class="arial"  style="font-size:20px;">Password: <input style="font-size:20px"  id="show_f" type="password" name="pass_f" maxlength='30'  size='15' class="password" >
  <input type="button" onclick="pass()" id="s1" value="show" style="height:25px; margin-left:5px;margin-top:3px;">
<input type="submit" value="connect" onclick="alert('Done!')" ></th>
<!-- password for sql login -->
  <th><p class="text" class="arial"  style="font-size:20px;">Password: <input style="font-size:20px" id="show_g"  type="password" name="pass_g" maxlength='30'  size='15' class="password" >
    <input type="button" onclick="pass2()" id="s2" value="show" style="height:25px; margin-left:5px;margin-top:3px;">
        <input type="submit" value="connect" onclick="alert('Done!')" ></th>

  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: `margin`? yes , no need to set `margin` both already same. @RafySalamMarbin